# How do you use explain with aggregate and cluster?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb sandbox with mongodb atlas and am querying using the native nodejs driver (not `mongoose`). When i run a aggregate query and use explain, i get the following error `"explain" cannot be used on an aggregate call with readConcern/writeConcern`.

I tried setting my connection `uri` with `w=0` but that didn't help. I didn't see anything in the docs for `options` in `new MongoClient(uri, options);`

I'm trying to measure query performance. How do you use explain with aggregate and cluster?

Answer (score 5):

For me, removing write concern option "w" altogether did the trick. Using nodejs driver 3.6. Things to check:

- Remove "w" and "readConcern" from options
- Remove "w" and "readConcern" from URI